# Is there a way to export all KWin Window Rules in KDE at once?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde5

One of the happy surprises switching to Ubuntu again from the ever increasingly bloated Windows (10) was to find the simple KWin Rules, very clear and with focus stealing prevention (its so disruptive to have a random or background confirmation pop up while working on something in Windows).

Anyway, I have one default one for application windows, and then others for specific windows (and then a setting for krunner screwed it up and so I'm trying to export all before resetting), but I just realized  export only does them one at a time. And I couldn't find any location for the actual config to backup. Below are a few links I could find and it doesn't look like there is a way export in bulk, am I wrong?

No response about a location for the config data:
https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=157045

General lack of import/export of KDE settings:
https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/8f4az2/is_there_a_way_to_export_and_backup_kde_setings/ and
https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/3bi2k1/is_there_a_way_to_export_settings_in_kde/

Comment: Have you looked at *~/.config/kwinrulesrc*? Maybe you can just copy that over to another system. Maybe the new system will "see" those rules after a logout or reboot?

Comment: If my comment works for you, please feel free to use it as part of an answer and then ping me by typing `@DK` and pressing `tab` to autocomplete my user name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by @DK Bose, ~/.config/kwinrulesrc is where these settings reside.